# Why does an APK file size of 7.6 MB allocate 1.36 GB on an exFAT formatted external hard drive when reverse-engineered?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, exfat, apfs

I have an `apk` file size of `7.6 MB`. When I reverse-engineer this `apk` file through [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), which is a reverse engineering tool for `apk` files, it allocates `1.36 GB` on an `exFAT` formatted external hard drive. Actually when I extract this `apk` file on my local drive (`APFS` formatted Macintosh HD), it allocates `32.1 MB` which is fair. What could be the reason behind this odd situation?

**Client:**

OS: `macOS Catalina 10.15.2`

Process: A typical `Java` process that is executed through a `jar` file